# Creating tile like structures in HTML5

Tags: html

Currently I am learning HTML which you can say HTML5 as its the latest. I wanted to create some tile like structure as showon below.

[image]

1. Logo
2. Website title
3. Navigation Bar
4. To show date and time
5. Table heading row
6. Table rows and colums

I will update the table cells with some data which I got from MySql query. I am confused where to use div and where to use just html text ect. For the below table to create do I need to put Div in each cell? Please advise how to proceed with this. If someone can give some html skeleton code for above structure I would be very much grateful.

Comment: C'mon man, at least show us what you got.

Comment: whats the alternative for div in html5?

Comment: header, nav, article, footer, section, aside...

Comment: I suggest you read [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/grouping-content.html#grouping-content).

In HTML5 divs should only be used as a [last resort](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) - when no other element is suitable e.g.) for styling unrelated content. Take a look at the following new HTML5 elements: header, nav, section, article, footer, ect.

Answer (score 1):

What you may need is the grid layout. Check out [960 grid system](http://960.gs/) or [twittter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)